# Can I pass a nested initializer_lists with different nested level in C++?

Tags: c++

I am constructing a `NestedInteger` class to store mixed type of int, or vector of int, or vector of vector of int. For example: `{1, {2, {3, 4}}, 5}`.
It seems that the element types in the list should be the same, because I declare the constructor as this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
NestedInteger(const std::initializer_list<T> l);
```

The elements should have same type `T`.

Is there a method to pass a list like this `{1, {2, 3}, 4}`?

Comment: @GaryNLOL Thanks. I want to find a way to pass parameters in such format like initializer_list rather than pass a string to enclose it. If no way, I have to choose parsing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::initializer_list<NestedInteger>` for the parameter, and provide a constructor for single integers.

Example:

```
struct NestedInteger
{
    NestedInteger(int x): stuff(x) {}
    NestedInteger(std::initializer_list<NestedInteger> xs): stuff(xs) {}
    
    std::variant<int, std::vector<NestedInteger>> stuff;
};
```

Test code:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const NestedInteger& is)
{
    if (std::holds_alternative<int>(is.stuff))
    {
        os << std::get<int>(is.stuff);
    }
    else
    {
        os << "{ ";
        for (const auto& it: std::get<std::vector<NestedInteger>>(is.stuff))
        {
            os << it << ' ';
        }
        os << '}';
    }
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    NestedInteger nest = {1,2,{3,4},{5,{6,{7,8}}},9};
    std::cout << nest << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
{ 1 2 { 3 4 } { 5 { 6 { 7 8 } } } 9 }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want exactly!